# SQL Server effectiveness of mirroring partial database

Tags: sql-server, database, replication, database-mirroring

Our database stores 200 TB of data. We've setup clustering options of two VM nodes with one storage but due to limited resources, we cannot replicate the entire database for disaster recovery (only about 100 GB can be spared at most).

So, I was wondering if it's possible to mirror partial portion of the database.

1. Distinguish active data, pull them into separate database (maybe at most 20 GB worth of active data)
2. Setup database mirroring for new database

Questions:

- If partial database is mirrored, should I be worried about performance issue?
- Are there other known solutions to prepare for DR situations?

It may be hard to provide best answer without knowing the detailed specs of servers, and configurations but I'd like to know how other servers are handled with limited resources.

Thank you!

Comment: It maybe be the folks that hang at https://dba.stackexchange.com/ will have some insight

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion hogan. Is it okay to just paste above question without deleting currently registered on in stackoverflow?

Comment: you may want to look at replication as you can do that at an object level